# How could I submit multiple forms?

Tags: python, html, django

How could I submit multiple forms (with the same names) created with for loop? Currently my submit button does nothing at all. Here's my code.

```
            {% for key, value in questions.items %}
    
                <form action="." method="post">
    
                <div class="question">
                    {{value.0.question}}
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    {% for answer in value %}
    
                        <div class="answer">
                                <input type="radio" name="answer-checkbox" value="{{ answer.id }}">
                                {{ answer }}
                        </div>
                    {% endfor %}
    
                </div>
    
    
                </form>
    
            {% endfor %}
    
    
        <input type="submit" value="Save">
```

Comment: could you provide the form code also?

Comment: This is neither a python nor Django issue. It is HTML and/or JavaScript

Comment: I suggest you have ONE form with all the questions and answers

Comment: Your use case seems pretty weird. Why would you submit multiple forms instead of just putting multiple inputs in one form? Please state.

Comment: The submit button will never work because it's outside the form(s) by the way.